# Cannot trigger function when clicking logo

Tags: css, vue.js, mobile

I have a logo that takes you to startpage when you click it. This works in desktop view but not on mobile view!? What can I do to make this work also in mobile view?
I have a vue-project.
The homepage is located at [eagleinstruments.se](http://eagleinstruments.se)

Hope you can help med solve this!

Best regards / Lisa

Comment: Did my answer helped somehow ? :)

Comment: I manage to locate the problem thanks to you :) But I havnt figured out exacly what to do to change it. hmm

Comment: `width: auto` didn't helped ? You could make some flexbox here. Do you have your code hosted somewhere for us to see what can be changed ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the menu navbar was overlapping on your logo. Your logo do have a `z-index: -1;` but here, the fix is to set some width to the `.wrap .hamburger` menu.
[image]

This could be enough, but of course you can make something more complex with flexbox or alike to make it more responsive depending of what can happen.

```css
width: auto;
```

I found this out by inspecting with the chrome devtools.